# Winforms Panel and Scrollbar issue

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel, intptr

This issue has bugged me for some time - when attempting to scroll down a Panel the bar will not move until the mouse is released (doesn't seem to be a problem in other controls).

In this forum http://csharpcode25.appspot.com/question/5080f1624f1eba38a4ca86bf the user has experienced the same problem and a possible solution is given by overriding WndProc - not sure if something got lost in translation from C# to VB but it just throws an error 'Type of argument 'Number' is 'System.IntPtr', which is not numeric.' at the first line. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
Public Class Panelx
    Inherits Panel
    Private Const WM_HSCROLL As Integer = &H114
    Private Const WM_VSCROLL As Integer = &H115

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        Try
            If (m.Msg = WM_HSCROLL OrElse m.Msg = WM_VSCROLL) AndAlso ((CInt(Fix(m.WParam)) And &HFFFF) = 5) Then
                ' Change SB_THUMBTRACK to SB_THUMBPOSITION
                m.WParam = CType((CInt(Fix(m.WParam)) And (Not &HFFFF)) Or 4, IntPtr)
            End If
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        Catch ex As Exception
            EmailError(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the calls to the Fix() method:

```
If (m.Msg = WM_HSCROLL OrElse m.Msg = WM_VSCROLL) AndAlso ((CInt(m.WParam) And &HFFFF) = 5) Then
    ' Change SB_THUMBTRACK to SB_THUMBPOSITION
    m.WParam = CType((CInt(m.WParam) And (Not &HFFFF)) Or 4, IntPtr)
End If
```

Comment: Hey Carko - glad someone is awake - thank you so much, that issue has bugged me for sooooooooo long :-)